# How has tethering changed in iOS 13?

Tags: tethering, cellular-carriers

How has tethering changed in iOS 13?

The UI in the Settings app is different, but I'm finding my Kindle Fire tablet can no longer detect an Internet connection when tethered to any of three different iPhones I've tested with - so I suspect something has changed and want to work on how to mitigate it.

I'm on Sprint if that matters.  We regularly used Tethering before iOS 13 successfully with a variety of devices.

Comment: I'm not sure if [these steps will help](https://appletoolbox.com/personal-hotspot-option-fix/) so I'm not adding it as an answer yet.  If any of these troubleshooting help you, let me know and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great list of things to try!  Unfortunately, I've gone through all of them that apply.  I should probably have also shared:  I'm able to tether my ThinkPad successfully, but not my Kindle Fire tablet.  FireOS is having issues with the tethering network now, but other things are continuing to work...